# Dynamic table creation at runtime with custom name without using inline (raw) SQL statement in .NET Core 8

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-8.0

Based on the subscriber registration, I need to create two tables with custom names in the same database.

Those are storing the transaction history for the respective subscriber.

I need this in .NET Core 8, code-first approach and using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: I found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925800/dynamic-table-creation-in-net-core

Comment: Dynamic table management is a bit non-idiomatic approach with EF Core.